# How to use paging in Facebook's iOS Graph API?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, paging, facebook-ios-sdk

I am going to be getting users groups for an app.  I am currently in a group that has 10,000 members, and this is not a uncommon thing to have.  I want to page all my requests for the user groups.  I am currently using

```
  [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/members?limit=10", @123456789]
                                 parameters:nil
                                 HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                          completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error
                                              ) {
                                 ...
                                 // set my "next" url here
                          }];
```

Which works exactly how I'd like.  I get my x amount of groups and I get my "next" url.

The problem is that the "next" url already has the "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/" in front of the url.  The current request that I am using already stuffs this piece of the url in there for me.  `[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:...`.  Parsing the url myself seems like a flaky operation, as the version could change and the group id will be dynamic.  I would like to use one `[FBRequestConnection` and reuse that callback that needs to be passed in for that method.

Is there a way I can get what I would like out of this?
Thanks!!